# How to detect phone inactivity on Android

Tags: android, restart, user-inactivity

When my app starts, a splashscreen appears and after this there is a slideshow with images. When user touch a image from slideshow, the app is closed (it is not working in background, it is killed). After that I need to detect phone inactivity to restart this app after 60 seconds of inactivity. Is it possible to do this, to wakeup the app after 60 seconds of inactivity?

Comment: Here is your answer.

Please use search before asking question.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208730/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-in-android

Comment: I don't understand that answer, I have see it before.

Comment: What is getLastInteractionTime or isInForeGrnd ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to set up an `AlarmManager` when your app is destroyed, which after 60 seconds will launch your app again.

You may find more about `AlarmManager` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html and here for an example: http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129

Hope this helps!

Comment: the problem is that app must restart not after 60 seconds the app is closed. It must restart after user not use phone for 60 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

possible Use `AlarmManager` with `BroadcastReciever` . send broadcast after every minute from `aLarmManager` . restart app in `onReceive`