# How to detect user inactivity?

Tags: android, android-service, user-inactivity

I'd like to run a service/background task that would detect user inactivity (that would be touching the screen or **unlock the phone**).

It would be used to detect that the phone is lost, and then send position informations to a server. Automatically (oh yeah).

How could I detect that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a **background service** to look if the android is not on user presence.

You can use android sensors, like **Accelerometer**, to detect if the phone is active. (if someone get the phone, the sensors will change)
And, you will need and wake up the service, in a regular amount of time, to check if the sensor has changed. If the sensor not changed at all in a large amount of time, the phone was lost.

Look at this: [How to detect user presence in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955782/how-to-detect-user-presence-in-android?lq=1)

And this: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html

Comment: Not a bad idea. I'll combine it with the solution I just found :)

Comment: BTW, I wasn't sure for a background service as I've never done that before, so thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should use Broadcast Receiver for ACTION_SCREEN_ON, ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ACTION_USER_PRESENT.

Read more here [Android - detect phone unlock event, not screen on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that. But if the user disabled the LockScreen, will this intent be still launched ? (I'll test it if i can ^^)

Comment: @Salamandar yes, it should work as well. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in fact I found an answer myself :p

I didn't think about screen unlock (or turning on) before writing down my answer… And then I found this :
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

I think it'll help me…