# How to use onUserInteration method in my code?

Tags: android

In my sample application in need find the user inactivity, ie if the user won't do anything for 5 minutes i need show a Alert Dialog. For this, initially i wrote my code in `onStart()` method in this method i include a thread with which is run 5 minutes delay but it doesn't meet the exact requirement, i searched in Google i got on predefined method `onUserInteracation()`, unfortunately i can't understand why this method (this method called when i interact the screen). Is it possible to find out the user inactivity through code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onUserInteraction is the correct function to check for any type of user activity. You can either set a timer which resets anytime onUserInteraction is called OR you can run a background thread that checks various constraints. I would probably go for a static timer instance that rests itself on user interaction.

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){
    //your static timer
    CustomTimer.getInstance().resetTimer();
}
```

Check out a lengthy discussion here: [How to detect USER INACTIVITY in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208730/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-in-android).