# Android - Handle user inactivity in the application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I want to detect user inactivity in my android application. When user log on the application  a thread will start execution and check the time interval. After log on the application if user interact with the device i need to reset the time and when the user did not interact with the device application and the time exceeds, then i need to display a dialog (DialogFragment) to intimate the user. When user click on the dialog i need to reset the time again.

In the activity we can use onUserInteraction() method and reset the time. But if dialog (DialogFragment) shown in the screen how to reset the time.

**And also we can use background thread for this concept or is there is any other way to handle this user inactivity in the application.**

Thanks
Mindus

Comment: Hint: A dialogue has buttuns, no? Regarding your question in bold text, it cannot be answered because you do not specify what exactly has to happen. But I presume a Thread is pure overkill and much too complicated. AlarmManager should be your friend.

Comment: Do you mean the user interact with the device or with your app?

Comment: Please go through this:
       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208730/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-in-android