# Implementation of Session Time Outs in Android

Tags: android, session, session-timeout

I am developing a reservation application and i have a requirement for the application to be timeout after 20 mins for inactivity in the application.

which ever the activity the application is in, it should navigate back to home screen (login screen) after time out

Kindly advice me what should be the better approach to do this.

Comment: Could you share with us what you have thought/formulated so far?

Answer (score 1):

Android does not provide any native support for tracking user inactivity per se. However, you can use a CountDownTimer and bind it with an interface callback like `onUserInteracted()` and reset the timer whenever it is called. You will also have to take into consideration the lifecycle of an Activity and register/unregister the timer/callbacks accordingly.

You can also refer this sample code to get a fair idea on how to get started - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481918/3025732