# How to detect user interaction in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a timer in my application and want to reset it on user interaction.

I tried adding onTouchListener but it blocks my onClickListener.

Comment: Please explain in a more detailed way and provide some code.

Comment: I have gave my answer ..kindly check my answer.. if you have doubt  then ask me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See this link
    [How to detect USER INACTIVITY in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208730/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-in-android)

There is method available in android activity called onUserInteraction with the help of onUserInteraction method we can find the user-interaction with particular activity

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction()
{
    MyTimerClass.getInstance().resetTimer();
}
```

Comment: @Scott but this is the solution how can i add above code as question?

Comment: Before going to post a question, do some initial search.

Comment: @KingofMasses  after long search i found this.. then i realise that this answer should be hightlighted so any body can reach this answer easily