# how can I get not-interaction time after user leave in application? android

Tags: android, system, sleep, user-interaction

want:go to login page after user no interaction in 5 min.
I can not found a method or something to get the exactly time. But how can android system decide when to lock screen? and user can set sleep time?
 can someone help me.

Comment: use Handler.postDelay()

Comment: Similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208730/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-in-android).

Comment: I tried. but there are so many activities.when I click button on fragment.It will not be called. @Exception