# How to get Auto Logout form Activity after 15 mintues due to InActive of user?

Tags: android

here is my code

```
public class LogoutService extends Service {
    public static CountDownTimer timer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        timer = new CountDownTimer(1 * 60 * 1000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //Some code
                Log.v("Timer::", "Service Started");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Log.v("Timer::", "Call Logout by Service");
                // Code for Logout
                stopSelf();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Start this service once user log in, and onFinish() method will be called once 15 mins over

Answer (score 3):

Create a BaseActivity class that needs to be extended by all activities.

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

    public static final long DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT = 900000; // 15 min = 15 * 60 * 1000 ms

    private Handler disconnectHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        }
    };

    private Runnable disconnectCallback = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Perform any required operation on disconnect  

           // Logout from app
        }
    };

    public void resetDisconnectTimer(){
        disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
        disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT);
    }

    public void stopDisconnectTimer(){
        disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction(){
        resetDisconnectTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        resetDisconnectTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopDisconnectTimer();
    }
}
```

In Other way this also will work.

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

   public static final int IDLE_DELAY_MINUTES = 15; // 15 min 
        @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        delayedIdle(IDLE_DELAY_MINUTES);
    }

    Handler _idleHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable _idleRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //handle your IDLE state

      // Logout from app
        }
    };

    private void delayedIdle(int delayMinutes) {
        _idleHandler.removeCallbacks(_idleRunnable);
        _idleHandler.postDelayed(_idleRunnable, (delayMinutes * 1000 * 60));
    }

        }
```

Comment: should i use both classes that written by u??

Comment: any one you can use.

Comment: sorry for late replied you can u tell how could i use mybaseActivity in my Activity classes??

Comment: For that you need to create a base Activity which having the above one of the functionality. then for all other your activities you need to extend your activity with your base activity.  Its Inheritance

Comment: can u please suggest me any example or github for that :(

Comment: https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/android-base-activity-class-example/  or https://github.com/erikcaffrey/Clean-Architecture-Android

Comment: Thanks For your Concern @king of Masses

Answer (score 2):

You can find user interaction using default method:

```
@Override public void onUserInteraction() {
 super.onUserInteraction(); 
}
```

check user interaction using this method and if no interaction found after your time limit, call logout method.

You can find more information using [How to detect USER INACTIVITY in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208730/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Handler` for that. Use it like

```
 android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler(); //declear them globly
        Runnable runnable=null;
```

Initialize `Runnable` inside `onCreate()` like

```
runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            finish();
            }
        };
```

Copy these two methods in your code

```
void start() {
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15));
}
void stop(){
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}
```

Override `onUserInteraction()` method of `Activity`and call `start()` and `stop()`

```
 @Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
    stop(); 
    start();

}
```

Don't forget to call start() method from `onCreate()` too after the runnable initialization.
Its `run()` method will call just after 15 minutes after user inactive, do your task there(you want to finish that `Activity` or something else)

**//////////=====Updated=====\\\\\\\\\**

Paste this `BaseActivity` in your code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
    private static Runnable runnable = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (handler == null) {
            handler = new Handler();
        } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
        if (runnable == null)
            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
              //do your task here
                }
            };
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        stop();
        start();

    }

    void start() {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15));
    }

    void stop() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

}
```

Now extends `BaseActivity` from all of your `Activity` except `AppCompatActivity` or else, like this.

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity{
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }
}
```

Do you task inside `run()` method, I suggest you to start another `Activity` and clear activity stack from `run()` method, because `finish()` will work there only for 1 `Activity`.

Comment: so i call handler my each activity??

Comment: You do not have to it from each activity(if you are having multiple Activities)    .... Make a BaseActivity class and extents AppCompatActivity in that class, apply that code here(call you login activity or else when run() calls),,,,,,,,,, Make sure your every activity have to extends BaseActivity class not AppCompatActivity or somthing else

Comment: can u perfer me any example for that :(

Comment: its great if that works for you, check the updated answer also.

Comment: yeah this is very useful for other's thanks for sharing your code @ajeet :)