# Clearing the SharedPreference data after some specified time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am using `SharedPreference` in my application. When application is started I am saving some data in it. I have one `Activity` on which I am performing all `Fragment` operations like adding, replacing etc. I need to remove that stored data from preference if I am not performing any actions in application i.e. application is idle for some time. How to detect that user is not performing some operations in app and remove data from preference after some specified time when app is stable?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208730/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-in-android)?

Comment: One way to use rx. This library can be useful for your task https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding