# How to set button visibilty off when no interaction is done

Tags: android

I have used `Handler` `#postDelayed` method, but it this makes button invisible after specified time irrespective of user interacting with button or not. How do I fix this?

Comment: you can use this link when user not interact    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208730/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-in-android

Answer (score 2):

To manually do change the visibility use:

`yourbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

or

`yourbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`